# React-router site map SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, babeljs

im using the package `react-router-sitemap` to generate sitemap for my react map but am facing the error in the title.

Here is my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "react-responsive": "^8.1.0",
    "react-router-sitemap": "^1.2.0"
  }
```

My .babelrc

```
{
    "ignore": [
        "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

and lastly my sitemap-generator.js

```
//Babel allows us to convert modern js code into backwards compatible versions
//This includes converting jsx into browser-readable code

require('@babel/register')({
    extends: './.babelrc',
})
//Import our routes
const router = require("./src/Router/routes").default;
const Sitemap = require("react-router-sitemap").default;

function generateSitemap() {
  return (
  new Sitemap(router())
  .build("https://www.blahblah.com")
 //Save it wherever you want
  .save("../public/sitemap.xml")
  );
}

generateSitemap();
```

Here's more information of the error log:

```
Users\neowenshun\Desktop\BlahBlahCMS\frontend\node_modules\rc-banner-anim\assets\index.css:1
.banner-anim {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Comment: seems like something is trying to import css as javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX Hi thanks for responding! Im pretty confused what's going on, i am able start the development server / build the app without having any errors...